# Socket and threads python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm just experimenting with this. Whenever a user opens the program he should get 'online' and listen for connections.
Here the GUI gets loaded.

```
class AppUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.parent.title("Redux")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.initMenu()
        self.initAudio()
        self.initMidi()
        self.initBroadcast()
        self.initFriendList()
```

But whenever I paste the code of my thread under `initUi`, it get's stuck on loading and my GUI doesn't show up. (keeps loading, because the thread is listening to connections)

```
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=Connection().getOnline("", 50007))
thread2.start()

Class Connection():
    def getOnline(self, host, port):
        self.s.bind((host, port))
        self.s.listen(2)
        print('Now online - listening to connections')
        conn, addr = self.s.accept()
        print("Connected to:", addr)
```

Why is my thread not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trouble is in this line:

```
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=Connection().getOnline("", 50007))
```

Here, you're actually *calling* `Connection().getOnline("", 50007)`, which blocks.  You haven't done this in the background, you've done it *before* your thread is started.  You need to adjust your call to look like this:

```
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=Connection().getOnline, args = ("", 50007))
```

Comment: bah too fast ... (+1 you beat me to the punch ...)